# Append Item to the end of List

Tags: c#

I am working with a link list. The list has items based on inserted values from textboxes (size, height, stock, price). . Through the button click the Add function takes values from texboxes and appends item but every time I add an item to the list instead of placing at the end of the list it always placed first. I am not sure why such behavior.  How can I modify so it can append the item always to the end of the list? (I am displaying my test results on a fifth multiline textbox called results).

**Code**

```
 public void Add()
    {
        textBoxResults.Clear();

        int stock = Convert.ToInt32(Stock.Text);
        string type = Type.Text;
        double price = Convert.ToDouble(Price.Text);
        int height = Convert.ToInt32(Height.Text);

        Tree = new FruitTrees();
        Tree.Stock = stock;
        Tree.Type = type;
        Tree.Price = price;
        Tree.Height = height;
        Total += Tree.Price * Tree.Stock;
        Trees.AddLast(Tree);


    }
```

Comment: Because this is how a linked list is normally implemented (for efficiency). And like you wrote it. Edit: Why not use the builtin `LinkedList` or `List` types?

Comment: @leppie How can I modify to append item the end but still keep it a linked list?

Comment: Your add method is wonky.  You don't need to do the first 2 lines in it.  Then just change any remaining references to Sample to be the parameter newItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own AddLast, something like this:

```
FruitTrees item = Trees.Retrieve(0); 
while (item.Next != null)
{
  item = item.Next;
}
item.Next = NewItem
```

Comment: +1 I like your idea much better. Could you show a complete implementation of your answer with my question?

Comment: +1, @codexMachine23 did not you commented that "implement our own method to append item"? Consider writing some code yourself too...

Comment: `public int AddLast(FruitTrees newItem)
    {
        if (First == null) return Add(newItem);
        FruitTrees item = First;
        while (item.Next != null)
  {
     item = item.Next;
  }
  item.Next = newItem;
  return size++;
    }`
    
    Not sure what Add/AddLast should return though, because then you do return size++; you are returning old value, i.e. 0 if list is empty.

Comment: Just remember not only to complete assignment, but get something from it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a school project?  Just wondering why you aren't using `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>`.

```
LinkedList<FruitTrees> trees = new LinkedList<FruitTrees>();
```

It comes with its own `AddLast` method which does exactly what you want.

Also, I think your class name shouldn't be plural (FruitTree vs FruitTrees).

Comment: Yes I am aware of that way but it is an assignment and only required to implement our own method to append item to end of list.